# Proof that $f(x) = \frac{2}{1 - |x|}$ is surjective on $\mathbb{R}→(0,2]$

Tags: functions

How can I prove this function is surjective ? I'm not sure how to start.
$$f(x) = \frac{2}{1 - |x|}$$
on $\mathbb{R}→(0,2]$

Thank you!

Comment: Recall the definition of surjective. $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective if $\forall y \in Y$, $\exists x \in X$ such that $y=f(x)$. What is your definition for $R$? By letting $y \in (0,2]$ try to solve  $x$ for $y=\frac{2}{1-|x|}$, i.e., $|x|=1-\frac{2}{y}$ and see whether $x \in R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an error or so in your post because $f(\frac{1}{2}) = 4 \notin (0,2]$. If your function is $f(x) = \dfrac{2}{1+|x|}$, then yes, it is surjective, i.e $f(\mathbb{R}) = (0,2]$. Observe that if $r \in (0,2]\implies f(d) = \dfrac{2}{1+|d|} = r\implies |d| = \dfrac{2-r}{r}\implies d = \pm \dfrac{2-r}{r} \implies \text{surjectivity of f}$ .

Comment: Thank you! I saw you edit my question, that's what I was trying to type in haha

Comment: @FellipeBrancaccio: Sure. I thought maybe you would want it edited, so I went ahead and did it for you.